# How to prevent boost::python::extract<float> from accepting int

Tags: python, boost-python

I'm using boost::python::extract<> to convert the items in a boost::python::list to floats. My problem is with int's in python - `extract<float>` seems to regard int->float as a valid conversion, however I only want true float objects. Is there a way to force extract<> to be more conservative?

```
extract<float> value(o);
if (value.check()) {
  // This is true both for floats and ints
  a = value();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you can't tell `extract<float>` not to convert intergers to floats.

What you could do is to query the wrapped `PyObject`:

```
const PyObject* pyo = o.ptr();
if (PyFloat_Check(pyo))
{
    // True only for floats.
    a = extract<float>(o);
}
```

Comment: Great, that will do exactly what I need. Thanks!